# is enumerator thread safe after getting with lock?

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

I am wondering if the returned enumerator is thread safe:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    lock (_sync) {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

If I have multiple threads whom are adding data (also within `lock()` blocks) to this list and one thread enumerating the contents of this list. When the enumerating thread is done it clears the list. Will it then be safe to use the enumerator gotten from this method.

I.e. does the enumerator point to a copy of the list at the instance it was asked for or does it always point back to the list itself, which may or may not be manipulated by another thread during its enumeration?

If the enumerator is not thread safe, then the only other course of action I can see is to create a copy of the list and return that. This is however not ideal as it will generate lots of garbage (this method is called about 60 times per second).

Comment: For List of T, No, it isn't. You might want to consider immutable collections ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385366(v=vs.110).aspx ), or at the very least, collections that are explicitly threadsafe, such as ConcurrentQueue

Comment: Yeah `ConcurrentQueue` seems to fit the bill, thanks!

Comment: If anyone is interested in how MS has done the ConcurrentQueue I found their code implementation here: http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentQueue.cs/1305376/ConcurrentQueue.cs (very slow webpage)

Comment: Could anayone point to documentation of how ConcurrentQueue does its thread safety? I'm assuming it will be better implemented then what I can do but would be nice to see what the engineers at microsoft have done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not at all. This `lock` synchronizes only access to `_list.GetEnumerator` method; where as enumerating a list is lot more than that. It includes reading the `IEnumerator.Current` property, calling `IEnumerator.MoveNext` etc.

You either need a lock over the `foreach`(I assume you enumerate via foreach), or you need to make a copy of list.

Better option is to take a look at [Threadsafe collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provided out of the box.

Comment: Looking at ConcurrentQueue from the link this seems to fit my purposes better than rolling my own list.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx), to guarantee thread-safity you have to lock collecton during entire iteration over it.

> The enumerator does not have exclusive access to the collection;
>   therefore, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a
>   thread-safe procedure. To guarantee thread safety during enumeration,
>   you can lock the collection during the entire enumeration. To allow
>   the collection to be accessed by multiple threads for reading and
>   writing, you must implement your own synchronization.

Another option, may be define you own custom iterator, and for every thread create a new instance of it. So every thread will have it's own copy of `Current` *read-only* pointer to the same collection.

Comment: I fail to see how custom iterator with current property makes it thread safe? What about `MoveNext`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: if you define custom iterator, that has it's own iteration pointer and index, you create an isolation between different instances of that iterator, which leads to thread safity on *read-only* access, as I mantioned.

Comment: You're correct, my question is how does that iterator points to right index when we call `MoveNext`? It is not possible without a copy of the list because by the time you call `MoveNext` items may have changed in the list(by another thread). Isn't it?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Yes, but I'm talking about read-only access, from all threads. If all thread in that moment use the same iterator type, to roll over collection, and that iterator type is readonly, by implementation, access became read only.

Comment: Correct me if am wrong. If all threads only reads(no writes) you can pretty much use `_list.GetEnumerator()` itself which is threadsafe to enumerate unless the collection is modified.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: if different threads does not share the *same* instance of iterator, yes, you can avoid creating one by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> *If I have multiple threads whom are adding data (also within lock() blocks) to this list and one thread enumerating the contents of this
>   list. When the enumerating thread is done it clears the list. Will it
>   then be safe to use the enumerator gotten from this method.*

No. See reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx

> An enumerator remains valid as long as the collection remains
>   unchanged. If changes are made to the collection, such as adding,
>   modifying, or deleting elements, the enumerator is irrecoverably
>   invalidated and the next call to MoveNext or Reset throws an
>   InvalidOperationException. If the collection is modified between
>   MoveNext and Current, Current returns the element that it is set to,
>   even if the enumerator is already invalidated. **The enumerator does not
>   have exclusive access to the collection; therefore, enumerating
>   through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure.**
>   **Even when a collection is synchronized, other threads can still modify
>   the collection, which causes the enumerator to throw an exception**. To
>   guarantee thread safety during enumeration, you can either **lock the
>   collection during the entire enumeration** or catch the exceptions
>   resulting from changes made by other threads.

..

> *does the enumerator point to a copy of the list at the instance it was asked for or does it always point back to the list itself, which
>   may or may not be manipulated by another thread during its
>   enumeration?*

Depends on the collection. See the [Concurrent Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx). *[Concurrent Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267331(v=vs.110).aspx), [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx), [ConcurrentBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx)* all take snapshots of the collection when GetEnumerator() is called and returns elements from the snapshot. The underlying collection may change without changing the snapshot. On the other hand, *[ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx)* doesn't take a snapshot, so changing the collection while iterating will immediately effect things per the rules above.

A trick I sometimes use in this case is to create a temporary collection to iterate so the original is free while I use the snapshot:

```
foreach(var item in items.ToList()) {
    //
}
```

If your list is too large and this causes GC churn, then locking is probably your best bet. If locking is too heavy, maybe consider a partial iteration each timeslice, if that is feasible.

You said:

> When the enumerating thread is done it clears the list.

Nothing says you have to process the whole list at a time. You could instead remove a range of items, move them to a separate enumerating thread, let that process, and repeat. Perhaps iteratation and lists aren't the best model here. Consider the ConcurrentQueue with which you could build producers and consumer model, and consumers just steadily remove items to process without iteration